# how to get clientx on audio timeupdate

Tags: javascript

## Problem

I need to retrieve the `clientX` (horizontal mouse location) value after timeupdate is called. However, the timeupdate event doesn't return `clientX`, and I can't seem to find a way around this problem.

---

## Code so far (sample)

```
var point = {
    to: function(e){
        console.log(e.clientX); // returns undefined
    }
}

audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e){
    point.to(e);
});
```

Is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for? So far both **Google** and **StackOverflow** have returned no promising results.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `clientX` or `clientY` on that event. What you need to do is to capture and store the mouse position in another event. In this example I'm using `mousemove` to capture and store mouse position.

```js
let mouseX;
let mouseY;

var point = {
    to: function(e){
        console.log(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}

audio.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
});



audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e){
    point.to(e);
});
```

```html
<audio id="audio" controls src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/harley-davidson-daniel_simon.mp3"/>
```